# Sorting list of numbers

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, numbers, int

I am trying to sort a list of numbers from smallest to the biggest and print it. I've tried two things:

1.

```java
public class Sorter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = {1, 3, 8, 2, 5, -2, 0, 7, 15};
        int[] sorted = new int[numbers.length];

        for (int a = 0; a < numbers.length; a++) {
            int check = 0;
            for (int b = 0; b < numbers.length; b++) {
                if (numbers[a] < numbers[b]) {
                    check++;
                }
            }
            sorted[check] = numbers[a];
        }

        for (int c = numbers.length - 1; c >= 0; c--) {
            System.out.print(sorted[c] + ", ");
        }
    }
}
```

and this thing works, but won't work with repeated values, so I tried this other thing

```java
public class Sortertwo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numinput = {3, 2, 1, 4, 7, 3, 17, 5, 2, 2, -2, -4};
        int[] numsorted = new int[numinput.length];

        int n = 0;
        for (; n < numinput.length; ) {

            for (int b = 0; b < numinput.length; b++) {
                int check = 0;
                for (int c = 0; c < numinput.length; c++) {
                    if (numinput[b] <= numinput[c]) {
                        check++;
                    }
                }

                if (check >= (numinput.length - n) && numinput[b] != 0) {
                    numsorted[n] = numinput[b];
                    numinput[b] = 0;
                    n++;
                }

                if (n >= (numinput.length)) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int g = 0; g < numinput.length; g++) {
            System.out.print(numsorted[g] + ", ");
        }
    }
}
```

Where it relies on the thing that once the number from the first array is used (the smallest one is found), it has to be ignored when the program goes through the array next time around.
I tried to assign it like `null` value, but it doesn't work, so I assigned it to zero and then ignore it, which is a problem, because the list cant have a zero in it. 
Is there any like better way to go about it? Thanks.

Comment: Is there any intention that you write your own sorting algorithm instead of using standard `Arrays.sort` / `Collections.sort`?

Comment: no, i didn't know it has native function like this, i tried it (Arrays.sort(numbers)) and it prints out the array in same order, ill look it up, thanks. also, would it work for alphabetical sorting as well?

Comment: Yes, it will work with `String` collections/arrays as its natural ordering. Try it and check whether this is the sorting you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use:

```
Arrays.sort(numbers);
```

Comment: tried it now but it doesnt seem to affect the order.

Comment: @Runciter What did you try because that should works fine.

Comment: Are you sure? Tested this myself: `Arrays.sort(numbers);` `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));`

Comment: oh yeah, it worked, sorry, i just printed them in reverse.), great! definitely worked!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your first method then change this:

```
if (numbers[a] < numbers[b])
{
    check++;
}
```

to:

```
if (numbers[a] <= numbers[b]) 
{
    check++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is homework, using `Arrays.sort` as the comments suggest, should be the way to go

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class S {
    public static void main(String ... args) {
        int[] numbers = {1, 3, 8, 2, 5, -2, 0, 7, 15};
        Arrays.sort(numbers);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
[-2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 15]
```